# Using Charles to push scripts to code (like in fiddler)

Tags: macos, fiddler, charles-proxy

In fiddler I can use fiddlerScripts addon, and push my script through the method onBeforeResponse. Then i use auto responder to push my script. That way I can check my code on almost anything. Is this possible to do with Charles or another program that can run on mac?  How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you'd normally do this with in Fiddler is the `AutoResponder`, not FiddlerScript, although the latter is certainly possible, just complicated.

For Mac, you can run Fiddler in a [Windows or Linux VM](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/14-01-15/running-fiddler-in-virtualbox-on-mac) and use all of its features.

If you want to use Charles, the feature to use is its `Map Local` tool, which can return local files for remote requests, similar to Fiddler's AutoResponder.

Comment: I would like to push script which does not currently exists. map local allows me to change existing script. not to push a new one. In fiddler i push new one using FiddlerScript and the auto responder. Any idea how i do that?